# Javascript doesn't work in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="contentBI" >you should click here! </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and javascript file:

```
function doAlert() {
  alert("hi!");
}

function addevent () {
  theBI=document.getElementById("contentBI");
  theBI.addEventListener("click",doAlert);
}

document.addEventListener("load",addevent);
```

Javascript doesn't run.

Comment: Have you linked the JavaScript file ?

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu yes I put it in head tag. but I don't know why it is not displayed in question.

Comment: what kind of browser do u use ？addeventlistener won't work below IE8。a more better way to do this is using jquery library。

Comment: *"I don't know why it is not displayed"* There is no `load` event that is triggered on `document`.

Comment: @FelixKling I updated the question, before the head tag was not displayed.

Comment: @R3tep: Ah, that's what they meant. I thought it was just a reiteration of the question (why the alert is not displayed). Too early for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `window.addEventListener("load",addevent);` instead of `document.addEventListener("load",addevent);`
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mpus6p9r/)**

Answer (score 2):

So you want a document ready like jquery, try this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentloaded",addevent, false);
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpus6p9r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all of your code, the first issue you should tackle is telling your page where your Javascript is at.

Try placing your script between `<script> </script>` tags within your HTML file.

```
</head>
<body>


<p id="contentBI" >you should click here! </p>


<script>
function addevent (){

theBI=document.getElementById("contentBI");
theBI.addEventListener("click",doAlert);
}
document.addEventListener("load",addevent);
</script>  


</body>
</html
```

- It still won't work, most likely. But it's a start.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with using src. But to use src in a static site, you have to know the path to the .js file, and I don't. (In this case.)

Comment: Hopefully the OP knows the right path, so suggesting to inline it as a solution to the problem seems.... useless?

Comment: Perhaps. But, the OP has updated his question based upon responses like mine. The original response didn't indicate that he had linked the files at all.

Comment: Ah I see, you answered before the edit. I have to disappoint you though. The whole code was there from the very beginning, the answer was just poorly formatted. : https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8a93dd33-7ad1-468b-bfaf-0199fe4a21e6/view-source

Comment: Ah, very nice. I suppose i should view the source before answering huh?

Comment: That's usually what I do when I feel something is missing and it involves HTML (and then I edit it).